# No rule to make target /usr/lib/libX11.so

Tags: c++, linux, x11

I'm writing a program using the library SFML, which requires libX11. I just recently upgraded to ubuntu 11.04 from an older version, and ever since I did I can't compile my program. I get the following error:

```
make[3]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/libX11.so', needed by `lib/libsfml-window.so.2.0.0'.  Stop.
```

I thought maybe that when I upgraded Ubuntu that package was uninstalled for some reason, but according to Synaptic, I have libX11-dev (I'm just assuming that's what I should be looking for, but I'm probably wrong).

Edit:

Running `apt-get install libx11-dev` gives this output:

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libx11-dev is already the newest version.
  g++-4.4 libstdc++6-4.4-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 32 not upgraded.
```

and running with the --reinstall flag gives this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  g++-4.4 libstdc++6-4.4-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 32 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/3,104 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 279595 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libx11-dev 2:1.4.2-1ubuntu3 (using .../libx11-dev_2%3a1.4.2-1ubuntu3_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libx11-dev ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up libx11-dev (2:1.4.2-1ubuntu3) ...
```

Comment: Have you `apt-get install libx11-dev`?

Comment: I do not. There is an X11 folder however, with a timestamp of 2011-06-05 14:39

Comment: what does `apt-get install libx11-dev` output? It should give you /usr/lib/libX11.so . If it don't, `apt-get install --reinstall libx11-dev`

Comment: I've edited the original post with the output since the comments don't format it well.

Comment: @Alex, and still no /usr/lib/libX11.so ?

Comment: Correct. I have, however solved the problem a different way.

Comment: I am getting the same error Alex. What did you do to solve the issue of X11 files not visible in /usr/lib?

Comment: See the answer below, I simply rebuilt the projects I was dependant on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out a simple `make clean` on everything was all I needed. I'm still unclear as to what happened between updates, but everything compiles and works when I rebuild the project form scratch.